# CNAME working - but not for directories

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, domain-name

I'm currently trying to resolve a problem with getting a domain pointed onto another domain, but for some reason it isn't working as it should be - any help here would be fantastic.

The CNAME as been set and is, as far as I can tell, working.
We've pointed `example.co.uk` to `example2.co.uk`

Going to `example.co.uk` shows the page of `example2.co.uk`
However, directories are not functioning.

So regularly, `example2.co.uk/directory` - would work,
But `example.co.uk/directory` - does not work

What is happening here?

Answer (score 7):

It's not DNS CNAME problem. DNS only help clients to resolve IP from FQDN. If virtual host root works, then IP resolving works fine.

You need to check you web server configuration, and web server responce for `example.co.uk/directory` request.